# etoolbox ifblank error with xkeyval

Tags: etoolbox, xkeyval

I am trying to create my first class, which is basically just my ordinary preamble with a set of options. These options are handled by `xkeyval` using the following syntax:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2013/07/19]

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\DeclareOptionX{firstoption}[]{\newcommand\myclass@firstoption{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{secondoption}[]{\newcommand\myclass@secondoption{#1}}

\presetkeys{myclass.cls}{}{firstoption, secondoption} %sets all keys to their default values
                                     %unless set by the user


\ProcessOptionsX\relax

\LoadClass{memoir}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\title{\ifblank{\myclass@firstoption}{% check if firstoption is blank
                %do nothing
    }{%
        \myclass@firstoption: %
    }%
    \myclass@secondoption%
}
```

The last piece of code is supposed to output `firstoption: secondoption` if `firstoption` is not blank, but only `secondoption` in case of the opposite.

However, for strange reasons, the colon always appears, independently of whether or  not `firstoption` is set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right test to use is `\ifdefempty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{gaussler}[2013/07/19]

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\def\myclass@firstoption{}
\def\myclass@secondoption{}

\DeclareOptionX{firstoption}[]{\def\myclass@firstoption{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{secondoption}[]{\def\myclass@secondoption{#1}}


\ProcessOptionsX\relax

\LoadClass{memoir}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\title{\ifdefempty{\myclass@firstoption}{% check if firstoption is blank
                %do nothing
    }{%
        \myclass@firstoption: %
    }%
    \myclass@secondoption
}
\endinput
```

> `\ifdefempty{⟨control sequence⟩}{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`
>   Expands to `⟨true⟩` if the ⟨control sequence⟩ is defined and is a parameterless macro whose replacement text is empty, and to `⟨false⟩` otherwise. In contrast to `\ifx`, this test ignores the prefixes of the `⟨command⟩`.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation of `etoolbox`:

> `\ifblank{<string>}{<true>}{<false>}`
>   Expands to `<true>` if the
>   `<string>` is blank (empty or spaces), and to `<false>` otherwise. The
>   `<string>` is not expanded in the test.

In `myclass.cls` the macro is called with:

```
\ifblank{\myclass@firstoption}{}{\myclass@firstoption: }
```

Thus, the unexpanded first argument contains `\myclass@firstoption` that is not "blank". Two `\expandafter`s help:

```
\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\myclass@firstoption}{}{\myclass@firstoption: }
```